# Can you deploy the solidus sandbox to Heroku? What are the security concerns that need to be addresses before "go live"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

After installing solidus as developer, the following command creates an application that's
utilizing the code:

```
DB=postgresql bundle exec rake sandbox
```

this creates a sandbox directory in your ~/solidus directory.
Can this sandbox be deployed to heroku?

I noticed that one needs to a) do a git init in that folder, b) add a .gitignore etc
to even begin deploying that folder to heroku/

If one does end up deploying it to heroku,
what security holes need to be capped before handing it to a customer in production mode?

Am I doing this the wrong way?

Motivation for this question: for someone modding solidus or an extension, the natural first parent application will be the ./sandbox/ application, simply because it's where the documentation points the reader at. So one of the motivations for me asking the question was to have some docco out there on the internet that helps folks considering pushing that folder to heroku

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help, but a few years ago I wrote a post to do that with standard solidus.

https://nebulab.it/blog/deploy-solidus-to-heroku-like-a-boss/

Comment: for someone modding solidus or an extension, the natural first parent application will be the ./sandbox/ application, simply because it's where the documentation points the reader at. So one of the motivations for me asking the question was to have some docco out there on the internet that helps folks considering pushing that folder to heroku.

Comment: There is also the [deploy to Heroku](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus#demo) button that will do everything in one click, although this doesn't address the original question it's worth considering if you choose that route.

Comment: Yes, the sandbox is not meant to go in production. It's just to easily test development changes, or for a quick Solidus tour. I'm not sure there are real security concerns, it's just a normal Rails application installed with some specific gems which links Solidus with a `path` option instead of using RubyGems.